# Слетает иконка (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Все иконки стоят на своём месте. А первая иконка слетает и заголовок. Почему так происходит?

```css
* {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.bg-orange {
  background: #f4a442 !important;
}
.sizep {
 width:280;
    height: 60px;
}

.data {
 position:relative;
 width:196px;
 height:60px;
}
.tur {
    position:relative;
 width:280px;
 height:60px;
}
.btn {
 width:138px;
 height:60px
}
.formInput > label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 42px;
    top: 12px;
    z-index: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.09;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    font-family: OpenSansSemiBold, sans-serif;
}
.formControl .formInputPlace {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.formInputPlace > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
 margin-left:40px;
}
.formInput>.far {
    z-index: auto;
    top: 21px;
    left: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #059bce;
    transition: top .3s;
    -moz-transition: top .3s;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s;
    -o-transition: top .3s;
}
.formInput .far {
    color: #c8ced1;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.formInputPlace p {
 margin-left:30px;
 margin-top:18px;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: margin .3s;
    line-height: inherit;
    color: #333 !important;
    font-family: "OpenSansRegular";
    transition: font-size .3s;
    -moz-transition: font-size .3s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size .3s;
    -o-transition: font-size .3s;
}
.search  {
  width:270px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css">

<div class="container py-3">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Город вылета: <span class="font-weight-bold text-primary"></span></a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item bg-orange">
      <a class="nav-link text-white bg-orange font-weight-bold" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Горячие туры <span class="badge badge-pill text-danger badge-light">-50%</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content "id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">

      <form>
        <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 search">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Дата вылета  </label>
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">С 13.07.2018</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 data">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Дата вылета  </label>
    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">С 13.07.2018</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 data">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Кол-во ночей </label>
    <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">На 7-8 ночей</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control border-right-0 tur">
    <div class="formInput">
    <label> Туристы </label>
    <i class="far fa-moon"></i>
    <div class="formInputPlace">
                    <p class="withoutKids">2 взрослых</p>
                    <span style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
   
          </div>
    </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn bg-orange font-weight-bold text-white">Искать</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      Тут ещё что-то
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию `.form-control` - `position: static;`

Необходимо добавить к `.form-control` - `position: relative;`